# Add-Type: chould not load file or assembly microsoft.office.interop.outlook

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to read from outlook-inbox by using the PowerShell code below:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.office.interop.outlook 
$olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders” -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace  = $Outlook.GetNameSpace(“mapi”)
$inbox = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInbox)
```

However I get the following error:

> Add-Type: could not load file or assembly
>   microsoft.office.interop.outlook, Version=12.0.0.0, ...

Answer (score 0):

> The interop libraries are not part of .NET framework itself, rather
>   part of visual studio.  you can copy the Interop library from
>   "Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for
>   Office\PIA\Office12"

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/585f86b2-c109-4dc0-aaff-a474d28e24c9/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftofficeinteropexcel?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Can you be more specific please ? Where should i locate the library ? Can i do it by using Outlook OWA or i must install Outlook client ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that .Net Programmability Support was chosen in the installation wizard of Office.

[image]

In that case all Office interop assemblies will be installed with Office.

Also you may consider installing them separately. See [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508).

Unfortunately it's not possible to do automation with the Click-To-Run Office editions. It's due to the virtualization process used. According to [the information here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/click-to-run-switch-%20to-using-an-msi-based-office-edition-HA101850538.aspx?CTT=1) you can switch your C2R-edition to a MSI edition. Read more about possible issues with Office 2010 in the [Office 2010 Click-to-Run compatibility with add-ins](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/982431/office-2010-click-to-run-compatibility-with-add-ins) article.